# getLastKnownLocation method always returns null

Tags: android, locationmanager

I have a problem to fixed position. I use `getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);`
but always return null, i have set the permissions in your `AndroidManifest.xml`.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
```

and enabled in Settings --> Location and Security --> location through network.

```
TextView locationShow = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.location);
    double latitude = 0.0, longitude = 0.0;
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        if (location != null) {
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }
    }
    else {
        LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                if (location != null) {
                    Log.i("SuperMap", "Location changed : Lat: " + location.getLatitude() + " Lng: " +
                        location.getLongitude());
                }
            }

            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            }

            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            }

            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            }
        };
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1000, 0,
                                               locationListener);
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        if (location != null) {
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }
        locationShow.setText("经度：" + latitude + "纬度：" + longitude);
```

I find that other apps can show the location correctly, so maybe there something wrong with my code.

Answer (score 4):

`getLastKnownLocation()` give the last valid cached location.

You are trying to get the cached location from the Network Provider. You have to wait for a few minutes till you get a valid fix. Since the Network Provider's cache is empty, you are obviously getting a `null` there.

Comment: thanks,so how can i modify my code to get the valid fix.A few minutes is a long time to wait.May i use the onLocationChanged to get it?

Comment: Of course you have to use the onLocationChanged method of the location listener. Getting a valid fix takes time (few minutes)

Comment: public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            if (location != null) {
                Log.i("SuperMap", "Location changed : Lat: " + location.getLatitude() + " Lng: " +
                    location.getLongitude());
                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                locationShow.setText("经度：" + latitude + "纬度：" + longitude);
            }
        }
I have wait for more than 10 minutes，but still fail to get the valid fix,so strange.

Comment: NetworkProvider requires that you are connected to the internet.

Comment: thank you very much,I find there are something wrong with google map here in China.I open the google map,and it can not get the valid fix,too.Other app use other map,not google map.Thanks a lot.

Comment: requestLocationUpdates dont work for some phones, Samsung ones that I have tested. lastKnownLocation works, but again for some phones only. I guess I will have to "wait" and check for "null".

Comment: @Siddharth I have had the same experience, with a Samsung Galaxy. Where the location update never comes.

Comment: Can you tell me which Galaxy phone? I'm pretty sure the `onLocationChanged()` callback is called, provided that you are in an open sky environment

Comment: When you say "open to sky", I guess you mean GPS Provider. Thats the point, I just hated the experience of my app when I used GPS Provider. So I shifted to a pure Network provider solution. And these phones just dont provide location update.

Comment: @Emil, since the onlocation never comes after registering with `requestLocationUpdates`, I started to use a Timer, getLastKnownLocation and called onLocationChanged myself.