# getLastKnownLocation() returns null ; it was working a day ago

Tags: java, android

getLastKnownLocation now returns null but it was totally working a day ago ! now it's constantly in null, from different phones.

what could be the problem ? did I implement it in the wrong way ?
The locationFetch thread runs constantly -with a while loop implemented inside- and is responsible for calling "onLocationChanged" function with each change.

```
Runnable locationFetchRun = new Runnable() 
        {
            public void run() 

            {       

                tracker = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

                Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
                Location location;
                boolean enabled;

                // Initialize the location fields
                while( !isFinishing() )
                {
                    Log.i("Homepage","User id value "+user_id);

                     tracker = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                      enabled = tracker
                      .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

                     connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                     activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();


                     //Brick point

                      if(!enabled || activeNetworkInfo.isConnected()!= true)
                      {
                          continue;
                      }

                provider = tracker.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
                location = tracker.getLastKnownLocation(provider);



                if (location != null) 
                {   

                  gps_state = 1;
                  onLocationChanged(location);
                } 

                else
                gps_state = 0;




                }

            }
      };

      //Start location fetch thread
    Thread locationFetch = new Thread(locationFetchRun);
    locationFetch.start();
```

Comment: Try rebooting the device and make sure location enabled in settings. If all fine, I would recommend to use LocationClient to get current location

Comment: Also check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6854099/getlastknownlocation-method-always-returns-null?rq=1

Comment: Thank you for the advice Libin, it actually worked just now but after an hour or so of updating.. which made the thread kill my phone's battery. I'll search for locationClient & it's usage in the future.

Answer (score 0):

It didn't stop working actually, it was just taking a lot of time to fetch the coordinates.. I'll search for another solution to save time and phone battery ; starting from changing the whole function to setting a decent timeout at the end of the loop.