# Get LastKnownLocation in Android returns null

Tags: android, locationmanager

I am trying to fetch lastknown location but it is giving me null value. I tested whether GPS is enabled or not, it's returning true.

Even I went into Google Maps and pointed my location (thinking that location data might be cleared) but it still didn't work.

Here is my Code

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        boolean isgps=locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        Log.v("is GPs Enabled",isgps+"");
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        updateNewLocation(location);
    }

    private void updateNewLocation(Location location) {
        TextView myLocationText=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.myLocation);
        if(location!=null){
            double lat=location.getLatitude();
            double lng=location.getLongitude();
            myLocationText.setText("lat:"+lat+"\nlong:"+lng);
            Log.v("Location","lat:"+lat+"\nlong:"+lng);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Might be helpful for you http://stackoverflow.com/a/10524443/6178443

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getLastKnownLocation method always returns null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6854099/getlastknownlocation-method-always-returns-null)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi why trying to use **getLastKnownLocation**.It return your previous latitude and longitude.Most probably it retrun you null.It takes time to update and it return previous lat lng.It could be very old or new old.Its not accurate and correct. So,Its better you go for new approach.

I'm just referring you **google Fused api** for location any kind of updation or current.Its very accurate.

How you can fused api in your project.See i'll give you small example.

**Step 1. Make this class GoogleLocationService.java**

```
public class GoogleLocationService {
private GoogleServicesCallbacks callbacks = new GoogleServicesCallbacks();
LocationUpdateListener locationUpdateListener;
Context activity;
protected GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
protected LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

public static final long UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS = 30000;


public GoogleLocationService(Context activity, LocationUpdateListener locationUpdateListener) {
    this.locationUpdateListener = locationUpdateListener;
    this.activity = activity;
    buildGoogleApiClient();
}

protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    //Log.i(TAG, "Building GoogleApiClient");
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(activity)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(callbacks)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(callbacks)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
    createLocationRequest();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

protected void createLocationRequest() {
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

}

private class GoogleServicesCallbacks implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        startLocationUpdates();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

        if (connectionResult.getErrorCode() == ConnectionResult.SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED) {
            Toast.makeText(activity, "Google play service not updated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
        locationUpdateListener.cannotReceiveLocationUpdates();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if (location.hasAccuracy()) {
            if (location.getAccuracy() < 30) {
                locationUpdateListener.updateLocation(location);
            }
        }
    }
}

private static boolean locationEnabled(Context context) {
    boolean gps_enabled = false;
    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    try {
        gps_enabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return gps_enabled;
}

private boolean servicesConnected(Context context) {
    return isPackageInstalled(GooglePlayServicesUtil.GOOGLE_PLAY_STORE_PACKAGE, context);
}

private boolean isPackageInstalled(String packagename, Context context) {
    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
    try {
        pm.getPackageInfo(packagename, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
        return true;
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}


public void startUpdates() {
    /*
     * Connect the client. Don't re-start any requests here; instead, wait
     * for onResume()
     */
    if (servicesConnected(activity)) {
        if (locationEnabled(activity)) {
            locationUpdateListener.canReceiveLocationUpdates();
            startLocationUpdates();
        } else {
            locationUpdateListener.cannotReceiveLocationUpdates();
            Toast.makeText(activity, "Unable to get your location.Please turn on your device Gps", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } else {
        locationUpdateListener.cannotReceiveLocationUpdates();
        Toast.makeText(activity, "Google play service not available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

//stop location updates
public void stopUpdates() {
    stopLocationUpdates();
}

//start location updates
private void startLocationUpdates() {

    if (checkSelfPermission(activity, ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && checkSelfPermission(activity, ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, callbacks);
    }
}

public void stopLocationUpdates() {
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, callbacks);
    }
}

public void startGoogleApi() {
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

public void closeGoogleApi() {
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
}

 }
```

**Step2. Make this interface 
LocationUpdateListener.java**

```
 public interface LocationUpdateListener {

/**
 * Called immediately the service starts if the service can obtain location
 */
void canReceiveLocationUpdates();

/**
 * Called immediately the service tries to start if it cannot obtain location - eg the user has disabled wireless and
 */
void cannotReceiveLocationUpdates();

/**
 * Called whenever the location has changed (at least non-trivially)
 * @param location
 */
void updateLocation(Location location);

/**
 * Called when GoogleLocationServices detects that the device has moved to a new location.
 * @param localityName The name of the locality (somewhere below street but above area).
 */
void updateLocationName(String localityName, Location location);
}
```

Step 3. Use this piece of code where you want to get location

```
private GoogleLocationService googleLocationService;

googleLocationService = new GoogleLocationService(context, new LocationUpdateListener() {
    @Override
    public void canReceiveLocationUpdates() {
    }

    @Override
    public void cannotReceiveLocationUpdates() {
    }

    //update location to our servers for tracking purpose
    @Override
    public void updateLocation(Location location) {
        if (location != null ) {
            Timber.e("updated location %1$s %2$s", location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void updateLocationName(String localityName, Location location) {

        googleLocationService.stopLocationUpdates();
    }
});
googleLocationService.startUpdates();


and call this onDestroy 
if (googleLocationService != null) {
    googleLocationService.stopLocationUpdates();
}
```

Thanks hope this help you.